# Running a function when enter is pressed in a text box

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

This is my input form:

```
<input type="text" id="word" />
```

I basically want a JavaScript function to execute when the person presses enter in the text box. I'm sorry if this is an obvious question, I couldn't find an existing answer that matched my needs.

Comment: `abracadabra(I pushed Enter);` !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`keyup()`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) is your answer:

```
$('#word').keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        // Do your stuff
    }
});
```

`e.which` returns the scan/character code of the pressed key. `13` is for `ENTER`.

You can find other codes [here](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes).

Comment: After reading some standards, both are arguably usable, but which is more preferable. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#word').on('keyup', function(e){
  if(e.which === 13){
    // User pressed enter
  }
});
```

Testing the event `which` property will tell you what key the user has pressed.
`which` is normalized by jQuery, so you won't have any cross-browser issues.